# Multiple sort using SQL SELECT Query using PHP and Form

Tags: php, sql

I use a html form with 6 criterias, using `$_POST` lat's convert criterias in variables like here:

Case 1 - All criterias are default
`$core = null; $mhz = null; $ram = null; $cam = null; $mAh = null $screen = null`
The correct sql query is this :
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY performanta_cpu_core DESC, performanta_cpu DESC, performanta_rami DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";`

Case 2 -  Only one criteria is set
`$core = null; $mhz = "performanta_cpu=1400"; $ram = null; $cam = null; $mAh = null $screen = null`
The corect query is this :
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $mhzz ORDER BY performanta_cpu_core DESC, performanta_cpu DESC, performanta_rami DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";`

Case 3 - Here is the problem All or more than one criterias ore setted:
`$core = 2; $mhz = "performanta_cpu=1400"; $ram = "performanta_rami=1024"; $cam = "camera_spate=3.2"; $mAh = "baterie_mAh=2250"; $screen = "densitate=441";`

I understand that i have need to make "`WHERE`" to be dinamic and visible just when any variable is set and also I have need an "`AND`" also dinamically like:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $core AND $mhzz ORDER BY performanta_cpu_core DESC, performanta_cpu DESC, performanta_rami DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";`
 I am stressed for a week with this and i cant advance without help...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Had to make screenshot. This question is art :) +1

Comment: Nice question, + from me also :D

Comment: Are you insist that One Criteria is working?

Comment: If you dont use special framework. in this part `WHERE $mhzz` you dont set a value to comparison. Please read the following text for better understanding dynamically query creating. [link](http://patrickallaert.blogspot.com/2007/09/building-dynamic-sql-queries-elegant.html)

Comment: please escape any untrusted values within your query with mysql_real_escape_string at least (don't forget to pass the current link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is terrible code and there are a million better ways to do this, but, this is the simplest explanation.

```
$parameters = array();
if(!empty($core)){
$parameters['core'] = $core;
}
if(!empty($mhz)){
$parameters['mhz'] = $mhz;
}
if(!empty($ram)){
$parameters['ram'] = $ram;
}
if(!empty($cam)){
$parameters['cam'] = $cam;
}
if(!empty($mAh)){
$parameters['mAh'] = $mAh;
}
if(!empty($screen)){
$parameters['screen'] = $screen;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE 1=1 ";
foreach($parameters as $k=>$v){
 $sql .= " AND ".$k."='".$v."'";
}
$sql .=  " ORDER BY performanta_cpu_core DESC, performanta_cpu DESC, performanta_rami DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";

// All of those parameters should be sanitized to prevent SQL injection.
// mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO.
```

Comment: how to put $sql? like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY performanta_cpu_core DESC, performanta_cpu DESC, performanta_rami DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
` or else?

Comment: Append it after. I've updated my response to reflect the change.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']' in E:\server\htdocs\performanta.php on line 26

Comment: this is line `$parameters['core'] = $core;`

Comment: I typoed all the brackets, I've updated my response to correct.

Comment: when I set an criteria gives me this `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\server\htdocs\performanta.php on line `

Comment: Check it out in action here: http://codepad.org/MFqx6vcE I am leaving for a while but I will check back this evening to see if you were able to duplicate my results.

Comment: Thanks again! I waitin for you

Comment: All is fine, now I get it work, but 2 errors persist: `Notice: Undefined variable: parameters in E:\server\htdocs\performanta.php on line 80` and  `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\server\htdocs\performanta.php on line 80`  but second one is because of error 1

Comment: I forget to specify, error persist just when all criterias are empty!

Comment: `$parameters` should be defined. See my first line where `$parameters = array();`? Do you have that line?

Comment: Yes, all working good now, but with code i've just edited in your answer. If any cryteria is not set, this means all variables are `null` `$parameters` becomes automatically also `null` ang gives an error, but if you escape him like if(!empty(parameters)) will work great! Thankyou for your work mkaatman!

Answer (score 2):

Excellently formatted question.. well done.

I may well be misinterpreting the question, however I think you're asking how to construct a query dynamically.
Perhaps you are not aware you concat strings ?

Eg.

```
if ($core != null) {$query.= 'AND core ='.$core;}
```

I hope this puts you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the beginning of your query, and to make the command easier to build add an "always true" WHERE condition:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE 1=1";
```

Then go through your variables and add to the WHERE condition as needed (the space before the AND is really important):

```
if ($core) $sql .= " AND performanta_cpu_core = '$core'";
if ($mhz) $sql .= " AND whatever = '$mhz'";
... and so on for the other four variables
```

Then append your ORDER BY and LIMIT and you're done (the space before the ORDER BY is really important):

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY performanta_cpu_core DESC, performanta_cpu DESC, performanta_rami DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Also, as Mahmut pointed out, you can't have `WHERE $mhz`, you've got to have `WHERE your-column-name = $mhz`.

Make sure you try out the query from the MySQL command line or WorkBench first. That will help you with syntax, including which columns need single quotes around them and which ones don't.

This isn't the ideal way to assemble a query but it'll work, and it looks like you're just getting started with PHP/MySQL so no need to throw you too much at once.

Answer (score 2):

```
$parameters = array();
if(!empty($core)){
    $parameters[] = "core = '$core'";
}
if(!empty($mhz)){
    $parameters[] = "mhz = '$mhz'";
}
if(!empty($ram)){
    $parameters[] = "ran = '$ram'";
}
if(!empty($cam)){
    $parameters[] = "cam = '$cam'";
}
if(!empty($mAh)){
    $parameters[] = "mAh = '$mAh'";
}
if(!empty($screen)){
    $parameters[] = "screen = $screen";
}

if (empty($parameters)) {
   $whereclause = "";
} else {
   $whereclause = "WHERE " . join(' AND ', $parameters);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name $whereclause ORDER BY performanta_cpu_core DESC, performanta_cpu DESC, performanta_rami DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']' in E:\server\htdocs\performanta.php on line 49

Comment: I fixed a missing parenthesis in `if(empty($parameters))`, does that fix it?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in E:\server\htdocs\performanta.php on line 44

Comment: I just checked, and there's no syntax error in my code. It must be elsewhere in your script. If you use a good IDE, it should help you find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to build your `where` clause

```
$conditions = array_filter(array($core, $mhz, $ram, $cam, $mAh, $screen));
$clause = implode(' and ', $conditions);
```

This keeps all non null elements as `$conditions` and then concatenates these with `and`. You can then use this as

```
'... where ' . $clause . '...'
```